# cron send STDOUT or logfile by mail only when STDERR is not blank

Tags: bash, cron, cygwin

I've seen many questions about only emailing STDERR, but that's not quite what I want.  When STDERR is not blank, I would like both STDOUT and STDERR to be sent to me, or, alternatively, the contents of a log file, which would accomplish the same thing.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, you want to send a logfile by email if the STDERR output is not blank.  In that case:

```
some_command 2>"$HOME/.errs.tmp.$$"
[ -s "$HOME/.errs.tmp.$$" ] && mail user@host -s "Error Info" <logfile
```

`-s` tests whether the file is nonempty.  So, the email is sent only if there were errors.

To clean up the temporary files, use this:

```
errs="$HOME/.errs.tmp.$$"
my_exit() { rm -f "$errs"; }
trap my_exit  EXIT
some_command  2>"$errs"
[ -s "$errs" ] && mail user@host -s "Error Info" <logfile
```

Note that the temporary file was put in the user's home directory.  Although probably not important here, this avoids the security issues associated with created temporary files in `/tmp` and hence the need for `mktemp` or other utility.